# Reporting Services Problem Rendering RTF

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rtf

I'm using **VS.NET 2005** and **SQL Server 2005**.  My development computer is running **Windows XP SP2**.  SQL Server 2005 database and reporting services are running on **Windows 2003 Server**.

My business requirement is to develop and deploy a report which takes rich text (**RTF**) stored in the database (**datatype = TEXT**) and converts it to an image at runtime using a custom assembly (source can be found here http://blogs.digineer.com/blogs/jasons/archive/2006/10/03/520.aspx).  I am able to generate and view the dynamic image containing the RTF on my local (i.e., developer) computer both using the **ReportManager** web interface and using the **Render** method.  When I deploy this to our test server, I end up with a broken link image.

To recap, I have taken the following steps.

**Created custom assembly** using VS.NET 2005 which converts RTF to bitmap image.  Custom assembly has a strong name.

**On local developer machine**

1. **Copied custom assembly** to C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
   8\Common7\IDE**PrivateAssemblies**.
2. **Modified** C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   Visual Studio
   8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies**RSReportDesigner.config**
   to include a **CodeGroup which grants
   FullTrust** to custom assembly based
   on **StrongNameMembership** (**NOTE**:
   ReadMe.txt doesn't mention adding an
   entry to this file).
3. **Modified** C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   Visual Studio
   8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies**RSPreviewPolicy.config**
   to include a **CodeGroup which grants
   FullTrust** to custom assembly based
   on StrongNameMembership (**NOTE**:
   ReadMe.txt doesn't mention adding an
   entry to this file).

**Modified report using VS.NET 2005 as follows**

1. **Added reference** to custom assembly
   and System.Drawing.
2. **Added image control** with
   type=**Database**, MimeType=**image/bmp**,
   Value = **call to custom assembly
   method**; method is passed value of
   database field which contains RTF.
3. Deployed report.
4. Viewed report successfully  both via
   HTML and via Render method of
   WebService using EXCEL as output
   format.  **HTML for image [image]**

**On local developer machine and server**

1. **Copied custom assembly** to C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting
   Services\ReportServer\bin
2. **Modified** C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting
   Services\ReportServer**rssrvpolicy.config**
   to include a CodeGroup which grants
   FullTrust to custom assembly based
   on **StrongNameMembership** (**NOTE**:
   source code indicates permissions
   should be granted based on
   **UrlMembership**).
3. Deployed report.
4. Viewed report unsuccessfully  both
   via HTML and via Render method of
   WebService using EXCEL as output
   format.  HTML for image

Initially, I got error messages when exporting to Excel along the lines of ,"data is missing" but these appear to have been resolved by granting permissions in .config files which we not mentioned in ReadMe.txt.  I've have run out of things to try and am at my wits end.  I am convinced the solution has something to do with permissions since this works on my computer but not on the server.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.

Regards,

Bill

Comment: Does your custom component work by creating an image file from the rtf data in the database or does it stream back the 'image' in a dynamic way?  If it uses a file as an intermediate, you might want to consider where the file is written and the permissions on that location.

Comment: the component is converting the rtf data to bitmap at runtime in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [grant your assembly the necessary permissions](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid87_gci1102094,00.html) to access the DB on the test server?  (Looks like you did.)

If so, then check to see whether you're actually creating the image on the test server.  If not, then it's a write permission issue.  If it's being created but can't be viewed, then it's a read permission issue.

Comment: yes, all database permissions are in place.  if they weren't I would be getting an 'access denied' error.  we don't actually create a file since the custom component converts the rtf data in memory at runtime.